# Using PHP's ArrayObject to implement a collection of model objects

Tags: php, model-view-controller, datamapper, redbean, arrayobject

I am developing a "fat model" for my [open-source project](https://github.com/alexweissman/UserFrosting/tree/slim), and I am working on the layer that will sit between the ORM (RedBeanPHP) and the controller.

I will have a `User` class, and probably a `UserFactory`/`UserMapper` class that can construct `User` objects, as well as perform meta-actions like `usernameExists`, etc.

A number of other SO questions/blog posts have pointed out that if I need to retrieve a **collection** of `User` objects, it would be inefficient to have my `UserMapper` class iterate through through the result set and build *n* `User` objects.

My idea then, is to create a `UserCollection` class which implements PHP's `ArrayObject` class.  `UserMapper` would be able to create a `UserCollection` that stores the raw result set internally, as a multidimensional array.  I could then implement `ArrayObject`'s iterator functions, `[]`, etc to construct the corresponding `User` objects on demand.

Is this a smart way to do it?  What do I need to consider before taking this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that [this is exactly how Laravel's ORM, Eloquent, does it](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Collection.php#L130):

```
class Collection implements ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Countable, IteratorAggregate, Jsonable, JsonSerializable {

...

public function fetch($key)
{
return new static(array_fetch($this->items, $key));
}

}
```

If the most popular PHP framework is doing it that way, I'd say it's a pretty good endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

To render big lists of data, it will in fact be slower using an instance per row. That's where the flyweight pattern comes in handy...
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/Flyweight/php

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this would be, as I'd expect User objects to have relatively little data in common.